# binary tree data structures

Tags: binary-tree

Can anybody give me proof how the number of nodes in strictly binary tree is 2n-1 where n is the number of leaf nodes??

Comment: The number of nodes in a binary tree is 2n-1 where n is the number of nodes in... what? n must not be the number of nodes in the tree, if 2n-1 is *also* the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: Though I suppose if n = 1, 2n-1 = n...

Comment: no its not hw its just that i was not getting how this comes so i asked...

Comment: Ah, **leaf** nodes. Gotcha. :)

Comment: @Mishthi did you get anything??

Answer (score 3):

Proof by induction.
Base case is when you have one leaf. Suppose it is true for k leaves. Then you should proove for k+1. So you get the new node, his parent and his other leaf (by definition of strict binary tree). The rest leaves are k-1 and then you can use the induction hypothesis. So the actual number of nodes are 2*(k-1) + 3 = 2k+1 == 2*(k+1)-1.

Answer (score 3):

just go with the basics, assuming there are x nodes in total, then we have n nodes with degree 1(leaves), 1 with degree 2(the root) and x-n-1 with degree 3(the inner nodes)
as a tree with x nodes will have x-1 edges. so summing

n + 3*(x-n-1) + 2 = 2(x-1) (equating the total degrees)

solving for x we get x = 2n-1

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that what you really want is something like a proof that the *depth* is log<sub>2</sub>(N), where N is the number of nodes. In this case, the answer is fairly simple: for any given depth D, the number of nodes is 2<sup>D</sup>.

Edit: in response to edited question: the same fact pretty much applies. Since the number of nodes at any depth is 2<sup>D</sup>, the number of nodes further up the tree is 2<sup>D-1</sup> + 2<sup>D-2</sup> + ...2<sup>0</sup> = 2<sup>D</sup>-1. Therefore, the total number of nodes in a balanced binary tree is 2<sup>D</sup> + 2<sup>D</sup>-1. If you set n = 2<sup>D</sup>, you've gone the full circle back to the original equation.

Comment: no i just want to know how 2n-1 comes if n is the no of leaf nodes in strictly binary tree

Comment: but in case of strictly binary tree it is not necessary that at d level 2^D nodes are present....

Comment: @Mishthi: when/if they're not, what you're trying to prove simply won't be true. Just for example, consider a binary tree of exactly two nodes. You can only arrange them as a root and one leaf. According to your equation, one leaf means it can only have one node, but we started by saying it had two. The equation only really works when the tree is balanced, and every level is "full".

Comment: no the equation works when the tree is strictly binary... In the above example of 2 nodes the tree is not strictly binary .. But consider a scenario in which we have 5 nodes such that root has 2 children left child of node has again 2 children but right child has no child... in this case the equation works and the tree is strictly binary as well as not "full" or complete also..

Comment: @Mishthi: perhaps it would help if you told us what you mean by "strict binary tree" -- you seem to be attaching some meaning to it of which I'm unaware.

Comment: strictly binary tree is one which have 0 or 2 children

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to work out a proof for: `N = 2L - 1` where `L` is the number
of leaf nodes and `N` is the total number of nodes in a binary tree.

For this formula to hold you need to put a few restrictions on how the binary 
tree is constructed. Each node is either a leaf, which means it has no children, or 
it is an internal node. Internal nodes have 3
possible configurations:

- 2 child nodes
- 1 child and 1 internal node
- 2 internal nodes

All three configurations imply that an internal node connects to two other nodes. This explicitly
rules out the situation where node connects to a single child as in:

```
   o
  /
 o
```

**Informal Proof**

Start with a minimal tree of 1 leaf: L = 1, N = 1 substitute into N = 2L - 1 and the see that
the formula holds true (1 = 1, so far so good).

Now add another minimal chunk to the tree. To do that you need to add another two nodes and 
tree looks like:

```
    o
   / \
  o  o
```

Notice that you must add nodes in pairs to satisfy the restriction stated earlier.
Adding a pair of nodes always adds
one leaf (two new leaf nodes, but you loose one as it becomes an internal node). Node growth
progresses as the series: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9... but leaf growth is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... That is why the formula
`N = 2L - 1` holds for this type of tree.

You might use mathematical induction to construct a formal proof, but this works find for me.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by mathematical induction:

The statement that there are (2n-1) of nodes in a strictly binary tree with n leaf nodes is true for n=1. { tree with only one node i.e root node }

let us assume that the statement is true for tree with n-1 leaf nodes. Thus the tree has 2(n-1)-1 = 2n-3 nodes

to form a tree with n leaf nodes we need to add 2 child nodes to any of the leaf nodes in the above tree. Thus the total number of nodes = 2n-3+2 = 2n-1.

hence, proved

Answer (score 1):

```
To prove: A strictly binary tree with n leaves contains 2n-1 nodes.
Show P(1): A strictly binary tree with 1 leaf contains 2(1)-1 = 1 node.
Show P(2): A strictly binary tree with 2 leaves contains 2(2)-1 = 3 nodes.
Show P(3): A strictly binary tree with 3 leaves contains 2(3)-1 = 5 nodes.
Assume P(K): A strictly binary tree with K leaves contains 2K-1 nodes.
Prove P(K+1): A strictly binary tree with K+1 leaves contains 2(K+1)-1 nodes.
2(K+1)-1 = 2K+2-1
         = 2K+1
         = 2K-1 +2*
* This result indicates that, for each leaf that is added, another node must be added to the father of the leaf , in order for it to continue to be a strictly binary tree. So, for every additional leaf, a total of two nodes must be added, as expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int N = 1000; insert here the value of N
int sum = 0; // the number of total nodes
int currFactor = 1; 
for (int i = 0; i< log(N);  ++i) //the is log(N) levels
{
   sum += currFactor;
   currFactor *= 2; //in each level the number of node is double than the upper level
}

if(sum == 2*N - 1)
{
    cout<<"wow that the number of nodes is 2*N-1";
}
```

Comment: but in case of strictly binary tree it is not always that the nodes at lower level is double of the previous level